# Axios response type <void | string> remove void

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am implementing some axios api calls and getting type errors with the expected response type.

I have tried a few different things and get slightly different errors with each.

I have a function that is being exported from context. This function should return data in an object.

```
interface JWT {
  token: string
}

interface SelectedContextType {
  getAuthJWT: (email: string) => JWT | void
}

export const AppContext = createContext<SelectedContextType | undefined>(
  undefined
)

  function getAuthJWT(email: string) {
    return securityAxios
      .get<JWT>(`/api/EmailAuth/${email}`)
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.data
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  const appContext = {
    getAuthJWT,
  }
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider value={appContext}>{children}</AppContext.Provider>
  )
```

This particular code gives an error on the above `value` prop. The error reads:  `The types returned by 'getAuthJWT(...)' are incompatible between these types. Type 'Promise<void | JWT>' is not assignable to type 'void | JWT'.`

I tried removing `void` from the code and got a similar error. I am guessing the `void` has something to do with an axios configuration, but either way I am not really sure why I would get this error.

Comment: "*I am guessing the void has something to do with an axios configuration*" erm, why would that be? You simply either return a string in the `.then()` or nothing in the `.catch()`. Which works out to `string | void` [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgRhgXhgBQE4gLYEsICmAdBgRCADYBuBAFAJQCwAUAPSsycwB6A-C1xhEoACwJhaDFAD4YAFgBMTZoKLAAhlGAjJ9GTFCRKxCiADmtJcpaHo8FOix5CJMpRoMW7QXwFdhYhJSyLKK9EA)

Comment: Do you understand what Promise means in general? (Are you familiar with asynchronous functions in JavaScript?)

Comment: Why would that cause this error?

Comment: @ruakh, yes I understand the React side of the code very well. I just haven't used TypeScript before.

Comment: Why would incompatible types cause an error? Erm, because that's what TS is for. Consider the code `getAuthJWT().then( x => x.toUpperCase() )` - if the code hits the `.catch()` in the `getAuthJWT()` function then `x === undefined` and you get an error. TS has helpfully pointed out that `x` can be string *or not a string* to help you prevent the runtime error. I don't see why it should be surprising that **Type**Script does stuff with **types**. It's the whole point of it.

Comment: @tdammon: OK, then, next question: do you understand (1) that TypeScript's complaint is "You're trying to put a promise in the `value` property, but that property isn't supposed to be a promise" and (2) *why* TypeScript is saying that?

Comment: (What I'm getting at here is that your question seems focused on the `void` thing, but TypeScript is 100% fine with the `void`. You don't even really have a TypeScript issue, you have a React/JavaScript issue that TypeScript is helpfully telling you about.)

Comment: @ruakh I see what you are saying. The interface for `SelectedContextType ` needs to show that the function will return a promise: `getAuthJWT: (email: string) => Promise<JWT | void>`